# Erro ao comparar string

Tags: c#

Estou tentando terminar minhas últimas partes do código e preciso verificar o valor de uma `string`, mas não consigo encontrar nenhum exemplo sobre como lidar. Eu tentei esse código, mas aparece o erro:

> Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
>   TestForm.cs 956 17

Esta é a minha variável:

```
public string malcoins = "0";
```

E este é o código:

```
if (malcoins = "100000")
{

}
```

Eu preciso comparar se a variável é = `100000`, senão desabilito o `button2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Troque o `=` por `==`:

```
if (malcoins == "100000")
{

}
```

Ou use [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (malcoins.Equals("100000") == true){

}
```

Ou ainda o [`Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx), que retorna zero se for igual:

```
if (malcoins.Compare(malcoins, "100000") == 0)
{

}
```